# R's "apply" to a multi-dimensional array a function that itself return an array

Tags: r

I have a 3D array of dimensions MxNxO. For each of the M arrays of dimensions NxO, I want to `apply` a function `myfunction` that takes as input a NxO array and return a NxO array.

If I do

```
apply(array, 1, myfunction)
```

the output is a 2D array of dimension (N*O)xM instead of a 2D array of dimensions MxNxO.

As an example, we can use the `identity` function from R.

Here is a 3D array

```
> a <- array(1:20, c(2,2,5))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   11
[2,]   10   12

, , 4

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   13   15
[2,]   14   16

, , 5

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   17   19
[2,]   18   20
```

and the `apply` result should be the same (for my needs) but it is a 2D array instead:

```
> apply(a,1,identity)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    3    4
 [3,]    5    6
 [4,]    7    8
 [5,]    9   10
 [6,]   11   12
 [7,]   13   14
 [8,]   15   16
 [9,]   17   18
[10,]   19   20
```

Also, I would like to preserve the labels on each dimension of the array (`myfunction` itself preserves those labels).

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for `aaply` in the **plyr** package:

```
a <- array(1:20, c(2,2,5))
> aaply(a,1,identity)
, ,  = 1


X1  1 2
  1 1 3
  2 2 4

, ,  = 2


X1  1 2
  1 5 7
  2 6 8

, ,  = 3


X1   1  2
  1  9 11
  2 10 12

, ,  = 4


X1   1  2
  1 13 15
  2 14 16

, ,  = 5


X1   1  2
  1 17 19
  2 18 20
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dimensions that your function will be returning (as you do in your trivial example), then you can us `vapply`.  I also would have suggested `aaply`, though I prefer the result to be 2 2x5 matrices, not 5 2x2 matrices (since `a[1, ,]` is a 2x5 matrix, so this makes more sense to me).

```
dim <- c(x=2,y=2,z=5)
dim.n <- lapply(1:length(dim), function(x) paste(names(dim)[x], seq(len=dim[x]), sep="_"))
a <- array(1:20, dim, dim.n)
vapply(dimnames(a)[[1]], function(i) identity(a[i, ,]), a[1, ,])
# , , x_1
# 
#     z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5
# y_1   1   5   9  13  17
# y_2   3   7  11  15  19
# 
# , , x_2
# 
#     z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5
# y_1   2   6  10  14  18
# y_2   4   8  12  16  20
```

Main advantage of this is it's all base package, so you don't need to include `plyr`.  The `plyr` answer is fine so long as you're okay with the interpretation of what the return dimensions should be, or don't necessarily know ahead of time the result format.

Also, I recognize the format here is nowhere near as clean as `aaply`, and wish `apply` respected the dimensions so one didn't need to resort to these things.  I had a [very similar question last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196818/3d-array-apply-3d-array).